# Calculating the probability that a student fails two consecutive exams?

Tags: r, string, loops, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. I have the following dataset - students take an exam multiple times, they either pass ("1") or fail ("0"). The data looks something like this:

```
id = sample.int(10000, 100000, replace = TRUE)
res = c(1,0)
results = sample(res, 100000, replace = TRUE)
date_exam_taken = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100000, replace = TRUE)

      id results date_exam_taken exam_number
7992   1       1      2004-04-23           1
24837  1       0      2004-12-10           2
12331  1       1      2007-01-19           3
34396  1       0      2007-02-21           4
85250  1       0      2007-09-26           5
11254  1       1      2009-12-20           6

my_data = data.frame(id, results, date_exam_taken)
my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$id, my_data$date_exam_taken),]

my_data$general_id = 1:nrow(my_data)
my_data$exam_number = ave(my_data$general_id, my_data$id, FUN = seq_along)
my_data$general_id = NULL
```

I was interested in finding out - suppose a student fails an exam, what is the probability that this student fails the next exam? (e.g. Fails the 1st exam - what is the probability of failing the 2nd exam? Fails the 5th exam - what is the probability of failing the 6th exam?). I  wrote the following loop to answer this question:

```
my_list = list()

for (i in 1:length(unique(my_data$id)))
    
{ 
    {tryCatch({
        
        start_i = my_data[my_data$id == i,]
        
        pairs_i =  data.frame(first = head(start_i$results, -1), second = tail(start_i$results, -1))
        frame_i =  as.data.frame(table(pairs_i))
        frame_i$id = i
        print(frame_i)
        my_list[[i]] = frame_i
    }, error = function(e){})
    }}


 final = do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_list)
   #################################################



library(dplyr)
total_1 = final %>% group_by(first, second) %>% summarise(totals = n())
total_2 = total_1 %>% group_by(first) %>% summarise(sum = sum(totals))

join = merge(x = total_1, y = total_2, by = "first", all = TRUE)
join$probs = join$totals/join$sum
```

The final answer looks something like this:

```
  first second totals   sum     probs
1     0      0   9817 19557 0.5019686
2     0      1   9740 19557 0.4980314
3     1      0   9727 19498 0.4988717
4     1      1   9771 19498 0.5011283
```

**Now, I am trying to modify the above code so that the analysis is performed at the "Second Level"** - **that is, I want to find out the probability of a student failing the next exam given that the student failed the two previous exams?** As an example, supposed the student failed the 3rd and the 4th exam - what is the probability that a student will fail the 5th exam?

I think that the final answer should look something like this:

```
# note: "first" and "second" refer to any consecutive exams (not the literal first and second exam), and "third" refers to the exam occurring immediately after the "second" exam

  first second third totals sums probs
1     1      1     1    ...  ...   ...
2     0      0     0    ...  ...   ...
3     1      0     1    ...  ...   ...
4     0      1     0    ...  ...   ...
5     0      0     1    ...  ...   ...
6     1      1     0    ...  ...   ...
7     0      1     1    ...  ...   ...
8     1      0     0    ...  ...   ...
```

I tried to manually modify my code for these requirements:

```
library(stringr)
my_list = list()

for (i in 1:length(unique(my_data$id)))

{ 
    {tryCatch({


start_i = my_data[my_data$id == i,]

vals_i = as.numeric(paste(start_i$results, collapse = ""))
L_1_i = lengths(gregexpr("111", vals_i))
L_2_i = lengths(gregexpr("000", vals_i))
L_3_i = lengths(gregexpr("101", vals_i))
L_4_i = lengths(gregexpr("010", vals_i))
L_5_i = lengths(gregexpr("001", vals_i))
L_6_i = lengths(gregexpr("110", vals_i))
L_7_i = lengths(gregexpr("011", vals_i))
L_8_i = lengths(gregexpr("100", vals_i))

frame_i = data.frame(class = c("111","000","101","010","001","110","011","100"), values = c(L_1_i, L_2_i, L_3_i, L_4_i, L_5_i, L_6_i, L_7_i, L_8_i))
frame_i$id = i
print(frame_i)


        my_list[[i]] = frame_i
    }, error = function(e){})
    }}


final = do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_list)


final$first = substr(final$class, 1,1)
final$second = substr(final$class, 2,2)
final$third = substr(final$class, 3,3)


total_1 = final %>% group_by(first, second, third) %>% summarise(totals = n())
total_2 = total_1 %>% group_by(first, second) %>% summarise(sum = sum(totals))

join = merge(x = total_1, y = total_2, by = c("first", "second"), all = TRUE)
join$probs = join$totals/join$sum
```

As an example - to answer the original question, we would now query the results (assuming I did this correctly). Here is the probability of a student passing an exam given that the student failed the previous two exams:

```
 first second third totals   sum probs
1     0      0     0  10000 20000   0.5
2     0      0     1  10000 20000   0.5
3     0      1     0  10000 20000   0.5
4     0      1     1  10000 20000   0.5
5     1      0     0  10000 20000   0.5
6     1      0     1  10000 20000   0.5
7     1      1     0  10000 20000   0.5
8     1      1     1  10000 20000   0.5

join[join$first == 0 & join$second ==0, & join$third == 1,]
```

**I am not sure if what I have done is correct - can someone please help me correct my code (and possibly show me a "better" way to do this)?**

Note: These probabilities look two "uniform" and make me inclined to think I did something wrong...

Comment: Since we define that each student has a 50/50 chance of failing each event, you will find that all answers will be 50% chance of success for the next event, even if they failed the previous two.  The question appears to be more geared towards the assumption that failures may be indicative of future performance but our defined randomly generated data doesn't really let us figure that out. Looking at binomial distributions may help you get to what you're after.

Answer (score 4):

```
P(A|B) = P(B|A)*P(A)/P(B)
```

Where A is the probability of failing exam `n` and B is the probability of failing exams `n-1 and n-2`.

We can write a function to calculate `P(A|B)`

```
d <- my_data
d %>% 
  dplyr::pivot_wider(id, names_from = "exam_number", values_from = "results") -> dd

p_fail_given_failfail <- function(n){ #n is integer > 2
  #check if the student took the exam n. Remove them if they didn't.
  indx.na <- is.na(dd[, n+1])
  dd <- dd[!indx.na, ]
  
  #Calculate probabilities
  p_BA <- nrow(dd[dd[, n+1]==0 & dd[, n]==0 & dd[, n-1]==0, ]) /nrow(dd[dd[, n+1]==0, ])
  p_A <- nrow(dd[dd[, n+1]==0, ]) / nrow(dd)
  p_B <- nrow(dd[dd[, n]==0 & dd[, n-1]==0, ]) / nrow(dd)

  p_AB <- p_BA*p_A/p_B
  return(p_AB)
}

p_fail_given_failfail(3) #prob of failing exam3, given failed exam2 and exam1
#0.5084479
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I wonder if this code can be adapted to calculate the probability of passing the next exam given that the previous 3 exams were failed?

Answer (score 3):

This approach generalizes answering the question "if I have a coin-flip distribution, what would be the probability of the test fails the n + 1 test after failing the previous n events".

```r
## Define parameters
students = 10000L
tests = 3L

## simulate tests. 
##  Generates students x tests matrix of test results.
test_results = replicate(tests,
                         sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),
                                students,
                                replace = TRUE))

## determine student set that were failures up to test - 1
complete_failures = rowSums(test_results[, seq_len(tests-1), drop = FALSE]) == 0L
final_test = test_results[complete_failures, tests]

## summarize results
prop.table(table(final_test))
#> final_test
#>     FALSE      TRUE 
#> 0.5150162 0.4849838
```

OP may be more interested in binomial distribution. That is, with n trials, what is the probability that only 1 is successful. In that case, we can use `pbinom` similar to:

```r
pbinom(0.5, 1, 0.5)
#> [1] 0.5
pbinom(0.5, 2, 0.5)
#> [1] 0.25
pbinom(0.5, 3, 0.5)
#> [1] 0.125
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @cole but it may be negative binomial (R package rnbinom (p,n,r), since n = no. of exams before first pass (r=1),p=0.5 (probability of success in each exam) with each exam being i.i.d Bernoulli.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).